# Can't for the life of me get button + role assignment to work - discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, roles

I have been looking for help with this for a solid week now and tried a lot of things, but a lot of answers are outdated with the new Components update for discord.py

I referenced this video for this particular code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ntw43Sg35k

This is in a cog if that matters. It worked ONCE but I didn't realize it and messed up the code so I lost it...

It pulls up the embed and even the buttons, but it does not assign the role and the component comes up with "This interaction failed".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZX1r.png)
Any help would be super appreciated!!

```
import os, json, asyncio, discord, discord.utils
from discord import Embed, Color
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_components import Button, ButtonStyle, Select, SelectOption, ComponentsBot, component
from discord_components.client import DiscordComponents
from discord_components.interaction import Interaction
from discord.utils import get

#----- Import -----#

client = discord.Client()

def get_prefix(client, message):
    with open('prefixes.json','r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)
    return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = get_prefix,intents=discord.Intents.all(),case_sensitive=True,buttons = DiscordComponents(client))

#----- Class Code for f1r4 -----#
class f1r4(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client

    @client.command()
    async def f1r4(self,ctx):
        embed=discord.Embed(
            title='Floor 1, Room 4',
            url = '',
            description = 'You decide that it\'s time to move on. Maybe, somewhere safer too...',
            color=Color.green())
        embed.set_thumbnail(url='')
        embed.add_field(
            name = 'North',
            value = 'Insert an informative text dump here.',
            inline = True)
        embed.add_field(
            name = 'South',
            value = 'take two boogaloo',
            inline = True)
        embed.add_field(
            name = 'East',
            value = 'Boy howdy don\'t look at the actual descriptions lol',
            inline = True)

        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed,
                            components=[[
                                Button(label = 'North'),
                                Button(label = 'South'),
                                Button(label = 'East')]])
        
        def check(res):
            return ctx.author == res.user and res.channel == ctx.channel
        
        try:
            res = await client.wait_for('buttonclick', check=check, timeout=30)
        except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
            tembed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Need More Time?',
                descprtion = 'Try again once you\'ve had a chance to make your decision!',
                color=Color.red())
            await msg.edit(
                embed=tembed,
                components=[
                    Button(style=ButtonStyle.red,
                    label='Command Closed',
                    disabled=True)])
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            await msg.delete()
            return
        
        if res.component.label == 'North':
            member = ctx.author
            mrole = discord.utils.find(lambda r:r.name == 'F1R1',ctx.message.guild.roles)
            role = get(member.guild.roles, name='F1R1')
            if mrole in member.roles:
                await res.respond(content='You have a character in Room 1!')
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
                await msg.delete()
                return
            else:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                await msg.delete()
                return
        else:
            return

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(f1r4(client))
```

Answer (score 1):

`res = await client.wait_for('button_click', check=check, timeout=30)` should be `res = await self.client.wait_for('button_click', check=check, timeout=30)`.
There is also an typo on description for `tembed`.

Suggestions:
Don't import from `discord_components.client`. discord_components is supposed to export all required objects; using this breaks things if library decides to rename files.
`buttons = DiscordComponents(client)` should be `DiscordComponents(client)` in separate line.